# pic16f628a internal oscillator setup error undefined symbol "INTOSC"

Tags: pic, oscillator

I want to set internal oscillator for pic16f628a, according to [datasheet page 96](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40044F.pdf), I have to set `FOSC_INTOSC`, but I get this error `main.c:11: error: undefined symbol "FOSC_INTOSC"`

if I set the other option `FOSC_HS` or `FOSC_LP` or `FOSC_XT` it works fine (no error)

but it's not working with `FOSC_RC` and `FOSC_INTOSC` .it's not because  for `FOSC_RC` and `FOSC_INTOSC`, there is two possible value for both of them (page 96 datasheet)?????

code :

```
#include<htc.h>
#include <pic.h>
#include <pic16f628a.h>
// Config word
__CONFIG(FOSC_INTOSC & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_ON & CP_OFF);

// Define LED pin
#define LED  RA0

// Define CPU Frequency
// This must be defined, if __delay_ms() or
// __delay_us() functions are used in the code
#define OSC 4
// Main function
void main()
{   
        TRISA0 = 1;                // Make RA0 pin output
        TRISB = 1;
        LED    = 0;                // Make RA0 low
    while(1)
    {
        LED = 0;               // LED off
        LED = 1;               // LED on
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `FOSC_RC` and se how it goes, I think some compilers use that instead of `FOSC_INTOSC`.

Comment: same error for `FOSC_RC`, I think because for `FOSC_RC` and `FOSC_INTOSC` there is two possible value for both of them (page 96 datasheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the appropriate #include file that your compiler is using for the particular chip you are using and look at it. That's the only way to be 100% sure what is (supposed to be) going on.

For example, here is a snippet from a HTC include file pic16f628a.h:

```
// INTOSC oscillator: CLKOUT function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OS/CLKIN
#define FOSC_INTOSCCLK       0xFFFD
// INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN
#define FOSC_INTOSCIO        0xFFFC
// EC: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, CLKIN on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN
```

The constant names are sometimes changed by the compiler supplier, and you may even find errors in the files, especially for very new chips.

Comment: yes it works, thanks a lot, specialty for this advice :)

Comment: I succeed to set internal oscillator as you said, but sill nothing work on my previous question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121311/pic16f628a-successfully-programmed-but-not-working , I just mad it like shown in the scheme, RA1 cant blink led, and RB5 RB6 RB7 even that they are set input, they turn on the led.

Comment: Did you follow my comment and set CMCON to 0x07?? This is not optional.

Comment: now when I set `CMCON = 0x07;` the RB5 RB6 RB7 stop turning on the led but RA1 still not working. one answer told me You must put a pull-up resistor to VDD on the MCLR pin, but even like that it's not working

Comment: You should get it to work on simulation (MPSIM) before burning it to the chip. Save yourself a lot of frustration.